# How can I get rainfall probability from yahoo API?

Tags: php, yahoo-weather-api

I need to get rainfall detail in my case ,

It's there mostly weather information in Yahoo API but rainfall,

how can I get rainfall probability from yahoo API ?

in the api response I don't get any detail about rainfall.

It's example response from Yahoo Weather Api

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2016-06-30T12:46:17Z",
  "lang": "zh-TW",
  "results": {
   "channel": {
    "units": {
     "distance": "mi",
     "pressure": "in",
     "speed": "mph",
     "temperature": "F"
    },
    "title": "Yahoo! Weather - Nome, AK, US",
    "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
    "description": "Yahoo! Weather for Nome, AK, US",
    "language": "en-us",
    "lastBuildDate": "Thu, 30 Jun 2016 04:46 AM AKDT",
    "ttl": "60",
    "location": {
     "city": "Nome",
     "country": "United States",
     "region": " AK"
    },
    "wind": {
     "chill": "45",
     "direction": "293",
     "speed": "11"
    },
    "atmosphere": {
     "humidity": "95",
     "pressure": "1017.0",
     "rising": "0",
     "visibility": "9.9"
    },
    "astronomy": {
     "sunrise": "1:39 am",
     "sunset": "4:31 am"
    },
    "image": {
     "title": "Yahoo! Weather",
     "width": "142",
     "height": "18",
     "link": "http://weather.yahoo.com",
     "url": "http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif"
    },
    "item": {
     "title": "Conditions for Nome, AK, US at 04:00 AM AKDT",
     "lat": "64.499474",
     "long": "-165.405792",
     "link": "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/",
     "pubDate": "Thu, 30 Jun 2016 04:00 AM AKDT",
     "condition": {
      "code": "26",
      "date": "Thu, 30 Jun 2016 04:00 AM AKDT",
      "temp": "48",
      "text": "Cloudy"
     },
     "forecast": [
      {
       "code": "26",
       "date": "30 Jun 2016",
       "day": "Thu",
       "high": "65",
       "low": "49",
       "text": "Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "32",
       "date": "01 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Fri",
       "high": "71",
       "low": "55",
       "text": "Sunny"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "02 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Sat",
       "high": "69",
       "low": "55",
       "text": "Partly Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "34",
       "date": "03 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Sun",
       "high": "64",
       "low": "50",
       "text": "Mostly Sunny"
      },
      {
       "code": "12",
       "date": "04 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Mon",
       "high": "49",
       "low": "47",
       "text": "Rain"
      },
      {
       "code": "26",
       "date": "05 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Tue",
       "high": "51",
       "low": "47",
       "text": "Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "06 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Wed",
       "high": "50",
       "low": "48",
       "text": "Partly Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "26",
       "date": "07 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Thu",
       "high": "50",
       "low": "49",
       "text": "Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "08 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Fri",
       "high": "58",
       "low": "47",
       "text": "Partly Cloudy"
      },
      {
       "code": "30",
       "date": "09 Jul 2016",
       "day": "Sat",
       "high": "56",
       "low": "49",
       "text": "Partly Cloudy"
      }
     ],
     "description": "<![CDATA[<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif\"/>\n<BR />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b>\n<BR />Cloudy\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<b>Forecast:</b>\n<BR /> Thu - Cloudy. High: 65Low: 49\n<BR /> Fri - Sunny. High: 71Low: 55\n<BR /> Sat - Partly Cloudy. High: 69Low: 55\n<BR /> Sun - Mostly Sunny. High: 64Low: 50\n<BR /> Mon - Rain. High: 49Low: 47\n<BR />\n<BR />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Country__Country/*https://weather.yahoo.com/country/state/city-2460286/\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a>\n<BR />\n<BR />\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)\n<BR />\n]]>",
     "guid": {
      "isPermaLink": "false"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```